# What is the difference between Soft mode and HAP mode for disabling Intel ME?

Tags: intel

Today is finally arrived the Dasharo Firmware with the option to disable the Intel ME from bios.
My question is: Which method is better? Soft or HAP? I actually choose soft, and seems no problem given.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. The answer is [here](https://docs.dasharo.com/dasharo-menu-docs/dasharo-system-features/#chipset-configuration)

As I understand

Disabled Soft: the firmware sent the command "ME_DISABLE" via MEI/HECI, the MEI interface is hidden by the os.

Disables HAP: the firmware set the the bit "HAP" in the flash descriptor, this method is more efficient because disable the ME firwmare before the Soft.